How do I add 6 spaces to the start of each line and add only 4 spaces for each tab from there in VSCode?
I'm trying to learn FORTRAN 77 in order to read some legacy code. Writing new code (say, for the purposes of a hello world script or exploring the ins and outs of do loops) is a bit of a pain when I like using 4-space tabs but need to start on col7 for proper syntax.
All that to ask, are there any VS Code settings that cause the first tab in a line to be 6 spaces, then every proceeding tab on that line to be 4 spaces?
I've tried setting tabs to 6 spaces, but I can't help feeling it would look better if the 6, 4 scheme were implemented.
I've also tried looking for VS Code extensions, but they're all aimed at Modern Fortran (and reasonably so, who the heck is actually still using FORTRAN 77?).
The tab scheme I'm hoping to have happen automatically is:
      program hello
      
      do 10 i=1, 3
          write(*,*) 'Hello, World!'
          write(*,*) 'Some life'
10    continue

such that the first tab on a line adds 6 spaces and proceeding tabs are 4 spaces.
--- edit ---
Thanks for the suggestions! I somehow never realized I could start later than col7 and just use 2 tabs instead of 1. I'll play around with that, it seems like a pretty clean solution.

You do not need to start at column 7. You can start at column 9 if you so wish (2x 4 blanks). This all is not about FORTRAN 77 in particular. It is about all fixed-form Fortran since first IBM versions through Fortran 66, 77 and then the fixed form in all more recent versions. Just because the source you are looking at uses the fixed form, it does not mean it is specifically F 77. For example, modern versions of Lapack use features from Fortran 95 and keep the fixed form.

And indeed the above code is at least Fortran90

Why 6? I have been using tab 8 and indent 4 for many decades. Alternatively, try 3. Customizing "tab stops" in the style of POSIX tabs or MS Word - the last century, it will be difficult to find one.
